# MVC WebAPI AutoFac Setting OAuth Options

Tags: asp.net-mvc, autofac

I am fairly new to AutoFac so please excuse me if this is a very basic question.  I am using the SPA Template in MVC 5 (Visual Studio).  In the Startup.Auth.cs file I have the following code

```
static Startup()
{
    OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
    {
       TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
       Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId, UserManagerFactory),  //I need to pass in UserManagerFactory through AutoFac
       AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
       AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
       AllowInsecureHttp = true
   };
}
```

I need to pass in the UserManagerFactory by resolving through AutoFac.  How do I do this?
In as separate class I have the following

```
builder.RegisterType<CRMUserStore<IdentityUser>>().As<IUserLoginStore<IdentityUser>>   ().InstancePerRequest();  //builder is an instance of ContainerBuilder in AutoFac
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to access the container and manually resolve the dependency like this

```
var userManagerFactory= container.Resolve<UserManagerFactory>();
```

This however means that you need to expose the container probably from your app/global.asax. This is a good central place to wireup autofac.

Another option would be to do dependency injection using the contructor of the class, but as this is something you do once and not everytime you instantiate a controller, I this the "manual" container resolving would do just fine.

Here you can see a snippet of one of my autofac configurations using WebAPI. As you can see I'm using autofac modules, this is just to "group" logic parts together into the container, you could just register as you do. With this approach, all dependencies to controllers will be auto resolved by Autofac, each and every time a request hits a webapi controller.

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {            
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        Initialize();
    }

    private static void Initialize()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        //register aptnet controllers
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        //register custom modules
        builder.RegisterModule<StorageModule>();

        //build container
        var container = builder.Build();

        // Create the depenedency resolver.
        var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        // Configure Web API with the dependency resolver.
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;

    }
```

Comment: This means I would have to make the Container static if I am going with the global approach.  Is this ok?  Cant I do it through something like GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService or something like that?

Comment: Both approaches would work. If you used static all over, then I could see a not so good pattern. But for a single place or two, why not. It's easy to locate and also test. The other approach also seems ok, then you just hit your kind of static globalconfiguration.